# How to retrieve the variable name “apple” in "FRUIT=apple" in UNIX shell?

Tags: linux, shell, unix, expr

When the user inputs `FRUIT=apple` in the Unix shell, how can I get the name `FRUIT` and `apple` from the input `FRUIT=apple` separately?

```
echo -e "\nEnter inputs here: \c"
read inputs

## user input "FRUIT=apple"
```

Is there any way to get a partial text from the input? 
Can we use the `expr` command to solve the problem? If so, how?

Comment: You shouldn't add the solution you used to the question. The question should only contain the, well, question.

Comment: You also changed the question to remove any mention of `expr`, which makes for example my answer look strange - why would I mention `expr` in there. I suggest you roll back your edit.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I have updated it.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it this way, for example:

```
$ IFS== read -r key value
FRUIT=apple
$ echo "$key"
FRUIT
$ echo "$value"
apple
```

Answer (score 2):

Try using `cut` command and pass the delimiter as `"="` . The right side of the same will be `apple` and left side will be `FRUIT`.

```
cat file_name | cut -d "=" -f1
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use `expr` with regular expressions like this:

```
$ str='FRUIT=apple'
$ key=$(expr "$str" : '\([^=]*\)')
$ value=$(expr "$str" : '.*=\([^=]*\)')
$ echo "<$key> <$value>"
<FRUIT> <apple>
```

The expression `expr string : regex` returns the number of characters matched, or (as used above) if there is a capture group `\(...\)`, it'll return that capture group. The regex starts with an implicit `^` anchor.

The expression for `key` matches everything up to the first `=` sign; the one for `value` captures everything after the (last) `=` sign.

---

All this being said, `expr` is a holdover from when shells weren't powerful enough to do text processing using built-ins; any modern shell can do it. For example:

- Splitting on `=` and reading into two variables:

  ```
  IFS='=' read -r key value <<< "$str"
  ```
- Using parameter expansion:

  ```
  key=${str%=*}
  value=${str#*=}
  ```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, the sum-up and explanation are clear. 
I was using `key=${str%=*}  value=${str#*=}` as the solution.